# Android (Xamarin) OpenTK-1.0 GL.DrawElements crash on call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, opengl-es-2.0, opentk

I have done a OpenGLES app on Android and Windows 7 (WPF)

I am using OpenTK on Android from Xamarin.

The code works perfectly on Windows but on android it crash when calling:

```
GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, indices, DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort, offset * sizeof(ushort));
```

But there is no logs at all in Visual Studio (Device log) or in CatLog. No exception rise in debugger. All vertex shaders and so on seems to load correctly.

I have set this feature

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

And in my subclass of GLSurfaceView

```
SetEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

But if I go back to use OpenGLES1.0 and using DrawArrays it works...
Any ideas why the app just stopping when calling DrawElements?